# How to convert Flow<List<Custom Type>> to MutableStateFlow<UiState>?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-stateflow

How to update `_uiState`'s `sumList` when get `Flow<List<Sum>>` from `room/repo`?
Thanks a lot!

```
data class UiState(
    val xxx: Boolean = false,
    val yyy: Boolean = false,
    val sumList: List<Sum> = listOf(),
)

class SumViewModel(repo: Repo) : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(UiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<UiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    //get sumList from room/repo
    val sumList: Flow<List<Sum>> = repo.getSumListFlow()

    fun updateXxxAndYyy() {
        _uiState.update { it.copy(xxx = true, yyy = true) }
    }

    fun updateSumList() {
        //problem: how to update sumList in _uiState from room<->Flow<List<Sum>> ?
        _uiState.update { it.copy(/* how to use repo.getSumListFlow() here?*/) }
    }
}
```

I've tried to use `List<Sum>` instead of `Flow<List<Sum>>`, but data won't auto refresh.
I expect to use `uiState` as the only source in `Screen Class` .